# How to find a particular x value for a given y value in a plot?

Tags: r, plot

I have this data set and I plot `F_1` against `ks`. I need to find the value of `ks` that has the maximum `F_1` value.

```
set.seed(1)
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
library(modelr)
data("heights")

ks <- seq(1, 101, 3)
F_1 <- sapply(ks, function(k){
  test_index <- createDataPartition(heights$sex, times = 1, p = 0.5, list = FALSE)
  test_set <- heights[test_index, ]
  train_set <- heights[-test_index, ]
  fit <- knn3(sex ~ height, data = train_set, k = k)
  y_hat <- predict(fit, test_set, type = "class") %>% 
    factor(levels = levels(train_set$sex))
  F_meas(data = y_hat, reference = test_set$sex)
})
plot(ks, F_1)
```

[image: This is the plot for this]

I can get the maximum `F_1` value from `max(F_1)`. But how to get corresponding `ks` value for that maximum `F_1` value?

Comment: Try searching for “arg max” — the arg max is the argument (the x) at which the maximum of f is attained. For example arg max of f(x) = -x^2 is x=0. Note that there could be more than one maximising x vaule.

Comment: @mrblewog How to do it I didn't get what is 'arg max'

Comment: Repeat with emphasis: try **searching for** arg max. I have told you the term to search, now use https://google.com to look up what it means and how to apply it to your case.

Answer (score 3):

To obtain the input value that corresponds to the maximum of the output you may simply make use of the index obtained from the output vector of your function.

**Example:**

```
f1 <- function(x){
  -x^2
}

# Input Values

z <- -100:100

# Corresponding Input Value(s) to max output

z[f1(z) == max(f1(z))]
```